# django, order parent object list by child list attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, subquery, django-queryset

I have some items that change hands and i keep track of all the owners and when they changed (using an **sqlite3** db). i want to get only the most recent owner for each item, ordered by owner's name. For example:

#### table items

| item_id | brand | serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BrandA | s22222 |
| 2 | BrandB | s33333 |
| 3 | BrandC | s11111 |

#### table owners

name is owner's name, and date is when owner changed. (in the example item 1 had 2 owners and item 2 had 3 owners.

| owner_id | item_id | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | B | 2023-6-22 |
| 2 | 3 | D | 2023-6-30 |
| 4 | 2 | F | 2023-6-20 |
| 3 | 1 | A | 2023-6-25 |
| 4 | 2 | E | 2023-6-21 |
| 5 | 1 | C | 2023-6-26 |

i want a django queryset to use in a template and have the **results** below:

| owner_id | brand | serial | item_id | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BrandB | s33333 | 2 | **B** | 2023-6-22 |
| 5 | BrandA | s22222 | 1 | **C** | 2023-6-26 |
| 2 | BrandC | s11111 | 3 | **D** | 2023-6-30 |

**"only one owner (the latest) for each item ordered by owner name"** or

**"all owners alphabeticaly with their items"**

---

#### models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField
    serial = models.CharField
    ...

class Owner(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, ...)
    name = models.CharField
    date = models.DateField

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date'] # last owner first
```

#### in the the html template i use:

```
{% for object in object_list %}...
and 
{% with object.owner_set.all|first as own %}
...
```

my best attempt so far is:

```
queryset = Item.objects \
    .annotate(last_date=Max('owner__date')).order_by('last_date')
```

or

```
queryset = Item.objects.prefetch_related("owner_set") \
    .annotate(last_date=Max('owner__date')).order_by('last_date')
```

both work fine for `order_by('last_date')`, but its not the sorting i want. When i change to `order_by('owner__name')` i get every item many times (as many as the owners it has)